# Regex for first x words in string

Tags: ruby, regex

I need a regex that returns the first `N` words from a string, including line breaks and white spaces. I tried with the following code, but the server crashes:

```
str[/\S+(\s)?{N}/].strip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this (for the first 15 words):

```
if subject =~ /^(?:\w+\s){15}/
    thefirstwords = $&
```

Just change the 15 to whatever number you like.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am sorry, I am new at rails and I don't understand the response, can you explain it? Does 'subject' is the string value? And what about 'match'?

Comment: @Flezcano Sorry for the delay. Yes, you got it right: `subject` is the original string, and `match` is the first 15 words. Let me know if you have questions. :)

Comment: So sorry for asking, but still dont get it, why the '$&'? thanks in advance.

Comment: @Flezcano `$&` is just the magic ruby syntax that means "the match". `$&` is a variable that contains the regex match. To reduce confusion, I changed the line in the answer to `thefirstwords = $&` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression

```
'/^.\S+(\s){N}/'
```

Start with any character and match up to N words.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I use str['/^.\S+(\s){N}/'].strip, I get undefined method for strip. Am I using it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can achieve this without even regex:

```
str.split[0...n].join(' ')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this already, but it seems to override the line breaks with blank spaces =(.